# List last N record from MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I have below `route` in my `app.js`

```
// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Entry.find({}, function(err, entries){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        entries: entries
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is displaying **all entries** in Entry collection. I would like to display only last 100 records from db. What is the best way to do it?

I am using with below `pug` layout.

```
extends layout
    block content
      h1 #{title}
      ul.list-group
        each entry, i in entries
          li.list-group-item
            a(href=entry.entryurl)= entry.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Entry.find({}).sort({ "_id" : -1 }).limit(100).exec(function(err, entries) {
    // Do something here
});
```

Comment: This is not loading any data.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use javascript to only send the last 100 items to the Pug layout:

```js
// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Entry.find({}, function(err, entries){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      let lastHundred = entries.slice(-100);
      res.render('index', {
        entries: lastHundred
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thats bad. you still load unnecessary the whole collection just to slice the last 100

Comment: Appearently this is the only working solution so far but is @Ifaruki mentioned i dont want to load whole data and slice it.